# Derivative under integral sign (minimal hypothesis)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^{d_1}\times\mathbb R^{d_2})\,\cap\, W^{\infty,p}(\mathbb R^{d_1}\times\mathbb R^{d_2})$ for all $1<p<p_0$.
Consider the functions
$$ F(x_2) \,=\, \int_{\mathbb R^{d_1}} f(x_1,x_2) \,dx_1$$
$$ G(x_2) \,=\, \int_{\mathbb R^{d_1}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(x_1,x_2) \,dx_1$$

Are extra conditions really needed in order to have $F(x_2),\,G(x_2)$ well defined and existence of
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_2}(x_2)=G(x_2)$$
for all $x_2\in\mathbb R^{d_2}$? Is it simpler if I require only absolute continuity of $F$ and the previous equality to hold only for almost every $x_2$?

Comment: Widely known as the Leibniz rule. Since you need Fubini in the proof, absolute integrability of $f$ is necessary.

Comment: @vitamind is it sufficient?

Comment: @vitamind moreover isn't it implied by the other hypothesis?

Comment: I don't really understand your question(s). Do you want to find the most general conditions on $f$ so that it works?

Comment: @vitamind I'd like to find the most general hypothesis on $f$ so that it works. It is unsatisfying to have to look for a uniform (local) control on the derivative in order to apply dominated convergence. I edited

Comment: Is the derivative in $G$ taken wrt $x_1$ or $x_2$?

Comment: @vitamind $x_2$ thanks, I edit

Comment: I think you need first one or two conditions on $f$ so that everything exists etc. and then a dominating function, which is not neglible. I imagine somthing like this: For a $g\in\mathcal L^1(\mathbb R^{d_1})$, $\lvert\partial_{x_2} f(x_1,x_2)\rvert\leqslant g(x_1)$.

Comment: @vitamind that is the classical hypothesis, yes, I think one could ask less

Comment: Right. In this special case it suffices that $\partial_{x_1} f(x_1,\cdot)$  is Riemann integrable over $\mathbb R^{d_1}$. The exchange of the integrals can be justified with Fubini-Tonelli.

Comment: @vitamind this is what I was looking for, would you write an answer?

Comment: @vitamind with Fubini-Tonelli approach the results holds true only for almost every $x_2$? Or is it possible to conclude for every $x_2$?

Comment: I found a bunch of related links when I posted this related answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4147220/moving-differential-out-of-integral-of-fourier-transform/4147231#4147231